# how can i make my function reusable whilst using the (e) parameter?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, arguments, anonymous-function, target

```
     const days = document.querySelector('#days');
     const hours = document.querySelector('#hours');
     const minutes = document.querySelector('#minutes');

      document.querySelector('#years').addEventListener('input', function (e) {

      let years = e.target.value;  

      days.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 365;
      hours.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 8760;
      minutes.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 525600;  


      });
```

I really need help with this one. When using the e parameter i can target the value from when the event is triggered using this code. I get that i can call the parameter anything and use target to access all the juicy information about the event in the console. What i do nott understand is , why cant i pass arguments with the e to make my function reusable. I want to pass my variables via arguments and store placeholders as parameters and work against them. Instead if I store (e) as a parameter, unless i am missing something , I am forced to reference my variables inside my function because I cannot seem to pass other arguments with (e) . Is there a way i can e.target.value and still pass arguments to my function? This one has really got me stuck , thanks

Comment: What are you trying to pass in? day, hours variables?

Comment: i want to pass in the days , hours, minutes variables , but i dont know how because if i pass them in and still try and reference (e) , (e) stops working, thanks for reply.

Comment: Seems weird to pass them in this case.

Comment: yes i agree there is no need for it, i just want to know if there is a way to do it, and if not how do they impact on each other as to not allow this, it will just help my understanding or it if i can figure it out? thanks again

Comment: You cannot use extra parameters next to `e` because you're not the one passing argument values to the call. You can and should however use closures to create different functions from the same source.

Comment: Could you give me a very brief piece of code of what you mean by closures and I will mark your answer up! Thanks

Comment: In this circumstance, if I pass other arguments via the function (e, years, days, hours, minutes) that doesn’t work when I add a parameter!! Totally baffled. Why can I pass an unreferenced e but not my variables as I would normally do?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to record the `id` attribute values for output parent elements as a data attribute on the `input` element used to enter a year. Another method could involve setting up a table of parent elements using the id of the `input` as key.

A third option is to add the event listener (which is passed an event object as argument) inside  a closure: i.e. inside an outer, reusable function which is called with all necessary argument values to add an event listener to a specific elements and handle events that are raised.

Here's an example of the first approach:

```js
"use strict";
function showDHM(event) {

    let years = event.target.value;
    
    event.target.dataset.for.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/)
    .map( id => document.getElementById( id))
    .forEach( (element, index) => {
         const multiplicand = [ 365, 8760, 525600];
         element.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * multiplicand[index];
    });
}

const year1 = document.querySelector('#year1')
year1.dataset.for = "days1, hours1, mins1";
year1.addEventListener('input', showDHM);
```

```html
<label> Year: <input type="number" id="year1"></lable>
<p>
<span id="days1"><span>days</span></span>, 
<span id="hours1"><span>hours</span></span>,
<span id="mins1"><span>mins</span></span>
```

Note the code is for demonstration only: adjustment for leap years not included!

---

The next snippet demonstrates the closure option. The conversion process used to modify the posted code was largely mechanistic: replace hard-coded values with argument names and include the modified code in an outer function.

```js
"use strict";

function handleYears( yearsSel, daysSel, hoursSel, minutesSel) {

     const days = document.querySelector(daysSel);
     const hours = document.querySelector(hoursSel);
     const minutes = document.querySelector( minutesSel);

      document.querySelector(yearsSel).addEventListener('input', function (e) {

      let years = e.target.value;  

      days.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 365;
      hours.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 8760;
      minutes.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 525600;  


      });
}

handleYears("#year1", "#days1", "#hours1", "#mins1");
```

```html
<label> Year: <input type="number" id="year1"></lable>
<p>
<span id="days1"><span>days</span></span>, 
<span id="hours1"><span>hours</span></span>,
<span id="mins1"><span>mins</span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Option 3 sounds like a feasible option. Could you give me a short piece of code demonstrating it please. I’d be super grateful?